# Minecraft for Ubuntu 12.04 does not pass done loading screen

Tags: games

When I try to run the Minecraft demo game on Ubuntu I get to a screen that says 
"Minecraft Updating" 
"Done loading" 
But it was never done loading. I am not sure if I am being impatient or there is something wrong because I have left the game to update and when I returned 15-20 min later nothing had happened. Please help I have been through many different forums and tried installing Oracle Java 7 which I removed for OpenJDK Java 7. I added the LWJGL package to the .minecraft folder and still nothing has happened.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Start minecraft from command line with `java -jar minecraft.jar` and note the error message. If the error message mentions lwjgl.so then use the solution from @Purplerob

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/"
```

before starting minecraft. The location might be different so you should hunt around in /usr/lib/jvm/[java folder]/ for a similar place.

I had this problem in arch and this solved it but because it was not ubuntu I'm guessing the location would be different.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason minecraft has stopped working with Java7 you should install openJDK6 and use that. To do so you should run `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`. Once this is doen make sure that that is the java being used by running

```
java -version
```

which should print

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

if it does not display that then run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` option.

Minecraft should work correctly after that.

(note if you are on a 32-bit machine replace `amd64` with `i386` and `64-Bit` with `32-Bit`)

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything, the only thing that worked was running it with Oracle Java 6 instead of Oracle Java 7.

See here for Java 6 install: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/11/install-oracle-java-jrejdk-6-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/